# Update UIScroller Offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Hi I am able to see my `UIScrollView` offset the first time but I would like it to be constantly updating and checking the offset as the user scrolls from left to right.

Here is what I have.

My `UIScrollView`

```
int PageCount = 2;

NSMutableArray *myArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"12-4.png", @"13-4.png", nil];

scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
scroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:scroller];
width = scroller.frame.size.width;
xPos = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < PageCount; i++)
{
    ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
    [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    width += scroller.frame.size.width;
    xPos  += scroller.frame.size.width;
}
```

And then the offset

```
if (scroller.contentOffset.x >= 0 && scroller.contentOffset.x <= 320)
{
     NSLog(@"Offset %f", scroller.contentOffset.x);
}
```

And that `returns 0`.
I would like to constantly update and check the offset.

I have tried `[scroller needsDisplay]` and `[scroller needsLayout]`

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn the basics of C:

```
 if (scroller.contentOffset.x >= 0 && scroller.contentOffset.x <= 320)
```

This assumes you want to see if the `x` offset is between 0 and 320 (inclusive).

To check the offset as the scroll view is scrolled, implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 0 && scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 320) {
        NSLog(@"Offset %f", scroller.contentOffset.x);
    } else if (...) {
    }
}
```

And of course you need to see the scroll view's `delegate` property.

Comment: Thank you for that, it was just part of demonstration for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What can I try to keep updating the offset? Ive tried `[scroller needsDisplay]` and `[scroller needsLayout]` as a way to update but that did not work

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Please clarify. Do you want to set the offset value? Just do `scroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(someX, someY);`

Comment: I want to perform something if my scroller offset is between 0-320 and then I want to perform something else when my scroller offset is greater than 320.  I want my code to constantly check the value so the appropriate actions are performed.  Does that make sense hopefully?

Comment: You need to implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method and check the offset there.